# Pandas and openpyxl - Exceeds Excel's limit of 65,530 URLS per worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I need some help for handling lost of URLs with xlsx.
I run Python with Pandas and openpyxl for gathering xlsx files and put them in a one xlsx file.

During the processes, The errors message shows up with this.
"UserWarning: Ignoring URL "~~~~~~" since it exceeds Excel's limit of 65,530 URLS per worksheet."

This error message appeared this week. I've been using the code for over 3 months, and I've never had a message like this before.
And even if I run the same code with the same files on another computer, it runs without any problem. (The URLs shows as a string, not clickable link.)

I run exactly same code! (Same version of python, pandas, openpyxl)
What's annoying is that the problem occurs on the PC I mainly use.

I try to solve this problem with Chat GPT, but it keep talking about openpyxl, and it does not help to solve the issue.

Isn't there an angel who can help me solve this problem?

This is a photo of the results from both computers.
PC1: https://i.ibb.co/FsxfFDC/image.png
PC2: https://i.ibb.co/TBRxjN5/image.png

Below is an example of my code.

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, colors, Font, Alignment
import openpyxl
from os import walk
import pandas as pd

path_1 = r"C:\Users\Jonkim\Desktop\Before"
path_2 = r"C:\Users\Jonkim\Desktop\Before\After"

f = []
f_name = []

# Save only the filenames of files in the working folder to the list
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path_1):
    f.extend(filenames)
    for i in filenames:
        temp_i = i.split("No_")
        if temp_i[0] in f_name:
            continue    
        else:
            f_name.append(temp_i[0])
    break 

# Group files with the same name
for j in f_name:
    group_f = []
    for q in f:
        temp_q = q.split("No_")
        if j == temp_q[0]:
            group_f.append(q)
        else:
            continue

    excel = pd.DataFrame()
    for file_name in group_f:
        df = pd.read_excel(path_1 + "\\" + file_name)
        
        df.dropna(inplace=True)  # Delete rows with empty cells
        df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)  # Remove duplicates

       # Save after final cleanup
        excel = excel._append(df, ignore_index=True)

   # Save the total number of rows in the final data
    las_row = len(excel)

    # Save as xlsx
    excel.to_excel(f"{path_2}\\{j}{las_row}.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: hint := `ExcelWriter`

Comment: That's because you can only store 65,530 URLS per worksheet in excel, this limit has been exceeded over the last 3 months. Hence, the URLs are stored as string now. Create a new sheet in the same excel file and store new URLs there.

Comment: HI, 

I noticed that I can store 65,530 URLS per worksheet.

The problem is that if I work on a file exceeding 65,530 URLS on a second PC, I can get results without errors.

Comment: do you have to use `Excel` for this? If you will work only with `pandas` then you could keep as `csv`